# Changing the content of ng-include from an ng-click from within the ng-include I want to change

Tags: angularjs

I have a template setup with a navigation at the top and the navigation links are like:

```
<a href="" ng-click="subPage='views/customers/jobs.html'">Jobs</a>
```

And those links change what is inside of an ng-include element:

```
<section data-ng-include="subPage" ng-init="subPage='views/customers/information.html'" ng-animate></section>
```

This works well, however after I load a partial into the ng-include putting a link like:

```
<a href="" ng-click="subPage='views/customers/jobs.html'">Jobs</a>
```

has no effect on the ng-include section.  I want to be able to change the content of this element from within the element.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ngInclude` creates a child scope, and because `subPage` is a primitive type (a string), `subPage='views/customers/jobs.html'` will update the `subPage` property of the child scope, but `subPage` on the parent scope will be unaffected.

This is probably similar to what you have right now, the links don't work...

```
<div ng-app ng-init="subPage = 'foo.html'">
    <div ng-include="subPage"></div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="foo.html">
        <div><h1>foo</h1>
            <a href="" ng-click="subPage='bar.html'">bar</a >
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="bar.html">
        <div><h1>bar</h1>
            <a href="" ng-click="subPage='foo.html'">foo</a >
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ckv57/)

There are two ways to solve this. One is to use `$parent`...

```
<div ng-app ng-init="subPage = 'foo.html'">
    <div ng-include="subPage"></div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="foo.html">
        <div><h1>foo</h1>
            <a href="" ng-click="$parent.subPage='bar.html'">bar</a >
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="bar.html">
        <div><h1>bar</h1>
            <a href="" ng-click="$parent.subPage='foo.html'">foo</a >
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RNL67/)

The other is to bind to an object instead of a primitive like a string...

```
<div ng-app ng-init="subPage.url = 'foo.html'">
    <div ng-include="subPage.url"></div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="foo.html">
        <div><h1>foo</h1>
            <a href="" ng-click="subPage.url='bar.html'">bar</a >
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="bar.html">
        <div><h1>bar</h1>
            <a href="" ng-click="subPage.url='foo.html'">foo</a >
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cHsAX/)

For more information, check out [this answer on prototypal inheritance in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/3199781).